# Whole schema migration from Oracle Spatial to PostGIS import using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, oracle-spatial, migration

I can migrate Oracle SQL table to PostgreSQL using ogr2ogr using:

```
ogr2ogr -progress -f "PostgreSQL" -nln schema.table -skipfailures -overwrite -lco FID=ID_COLUMN -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom PG:"host=localhost user=postgres password=yadayada dbname=database" OCI:username/password@server:port/database:schema.table
```

Is there a way to copy the whole schema?

Comment: No, or better: not easily. The proprietary [FME](https://www.safe.com/) can do that in batch, but you'd need a license. [This](http://gis-expert.com/wp/2018/09/12/how-to-migrate-spatial-data-from-oracle-to-postgis/) blog article might help you save some time running `ogr2ogr` for each table in a schema.

Comment: You can use scripting to run the conversion command for each table you want to move. Python for example: use it to build a lcatalof of tables to copy, then for each table construct the ogr command and execute it. You can also record progress: mark the catalog rows with success or failure, record timings etc